# Previous Function does not carry over to next function NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code so far. I am currently creating a program similar to hangman game and am unsure how to get over this little hump. ATM i am stuck on unable to pass defined variables in the function **loadwordlist():** to the second function called **gethint():** any tips on how to do it?

```
import random

def setup():

    print("Reading Word List...")
    print("Selecting Secret Word...")
    print("A secret word has been selected...")

setup()

def loadwordlist():

    word = open ('words.txt').read().splitlines()
    secret_word = random.choice(word).lower()
    guessed_word = []
    guessed_letters = []
    for letters in secret_word:
        guessed_word.append('_')
    return ' '.join(guessed_word)

print(loadwordlist())

total_guesses = 10
print(("You have {} guesses left").format(total_guesses))

def gethint():

    loadwordlist()
    guess = input("Please enter a guess:")
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess in guessed_word:
        print("You guessed Correctly")
        guessed_letters.append(guess)

gethint()
```

Comment: Place them in a common scope.

Comment: **loadWordList(filename)** Returns a list of words read from the file with the given name. All words should be converted to lowercase when read in.

**getHint(word, guesses)**
Returns the hint for the secret word word, given the guesses in the list guesses. The returned value should have an _ for each character in word that does not appear in guesses, or the character at the correct position if it is contained in guesses.
**countOccurences(word, guess)**
Returns a count of how many times the character guess appears in the word word
This is how i am ment to format it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignacio suggested placing them in a common scope.  He is correct, if you understand what that means.  Given your code, you might be new at this, so you might not understand scopes.  At some point, google 'python scope' (without quotes) and you'll find explanations.

A **minimal** fix is to move `guessed_letters = []` to the global scope (outside of any function) or inside `gethint()`.  Also, in `gethint()`, change the invocation of `loadwordlist()` to `guessed_word = loadwordlist()`.

The minimally modified program becomes

```
import random

def setup():
    print("Reading Word List...")
    print("Selecting Secret Word...")
    print("A secret word has been selected...")

setup()

def loadwordlist():
    word = open ('words.txt').read().splitlines()
    secret_word = random.choice(word).lower()
    guessed_word = []

    for letters in secret_word:
        guessed_word.append('_')
    return ' '.join(guessed_word)

print(loadwordlist())

total_guesses = 10
print(("You have {} guesses left").format(total_guesses))
guessed_letters = []    

def gethint():
    guessed_word = loadwordlist()
    guess = input("Please enter a guess:")
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess in guessed_word:
        print("You guessed Correctly")
        guessed_letters.append(guess)

gethint()
```

For a program this simple, functions are just getting in your way, because they restrict variables to the scope of the function.  Another fix is to remove the function semantics (the def lines and the lines that invoke them) so that everything is within the global scope:

```
import random

guessed_letters = []
guessed_word = []

print("Reading Word List...")
word = open ('words.txt').read().splitlines()
print("Selecting Secret Word...")
secret_word = random.choice(word).lower()
print("A secret word has been selected...")

for letters in secret_word:
    guessed_word.append('_ ')
print(' '.join(guessed_word))
total_guesses = 10
print(("You have {} guesses left").format(total_guesses))
guess = input("Please enter a guess:")
guess = guess.lower()
if guess in guessed_word:
    print("You guessed Correctly")
    guessed_letters.append(guess)
```

I modified your program as is, as little as possible, to illustrate the difference; there is more to do. For example, the program asks for the first letter, then terminates.

Also, it isn't a 'pythonesque' solution at this point, either, but for a first program, don't worry about that, just learn what you learn by making it work.  After it works, study python more and improve it based on what you learn.

I am also a python newbie.  Good luck!